# How can I scroll to the bottom of the object list quickly

Tags: interface, selection-tools, scene, select, navigation

I have a cactus with 3000 spines and I don't want to scroll all the way down to select them. How can I do this quickly?

Comment: You can move cactus meshes to a collection and select by collection. Or if they're named similarly select by any pattern in name using filter by name in outliner. Outliner will scroll itself to whatever selected in scene if you select object and press Numpad dot with mouse over its window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a scroll bar on the right. It's hard to see but it's there.

[image]